# Reading a .dat data file

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have a data file in the .dat format, along with it is an xml file.
What i need is to read the data from this .dat file and convert it into readable csv.

currently i am unable to read the content of this .dat file if i open it in excel.

After scrolling into alot of similar stackoverflow issues, i got that you need to know in which format your .dat file was orignally written, owing to the point it has .xml file along with it, i suppose it might be xml.

Anyhelp will be appreciated if someone can direct me to the right direction of decoding this file.

Here is a screenshot of the file if i open it in notepad or excel.[My .Dat File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYhH.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. You are right,".dat" is not a format specification. So where does the file come from? Which program saved it? How does it look if you open it in a plain text editor (is it ASCII)?

Comment: I have updated the original question and attached a snapshot of this file. I hope you can see that.

Comment: Btw, About your questions, it is basically a file exported by a software, similar softwares export these data files in csv, before exporting this file,  software asked about the delimiter and i chose a comma, so i was pretty sure it will be exported to csv, but to my surprise it is a .dat file.

I am able to read a few starting lines using pandas data frame, but decoding it is the issue.

Comment: Hi, if you could name the software maybe they documented the data format in the manual...but a software" is slightly too unspecific.